# Saving changes/updating existing object in dataset with Entity FrameWork and not have to set each property individually

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

Can I do something like the below (which does not work)  without having to explicitly set each property of the object. Product is the object that is created by the default model binder from a form submission and ProductInDb is object in the context/database that I wish to override/update. The ProductID primary key is the same on both.

```
var ProductInDb = context.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductID == product.ProductID);

ProductInDb = product;

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can attach the existing `product` and set its state as `Modified`.

If you are using `DbContext` API

```
context.Products.Attach(product);
context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

context.SaveChanges();
```

For `ObjectContext`

```
context.Products.Attach(product);
context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(product, EntityState.Modified);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Does not contain a definition for "Entry". Do I need to reference something ? Already using System.Data.Objects; What else ? Pressing ctrl + . gives nothing for Entry.

Comment: @LaserBeak It looks like you are using `ObjectContext`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Eranga please see my following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085654/pk-violation-while-updating-via-ef/16086406?noredirect=1#16086406

Comment: @Eranga I have tried the same thing, but got uniquness violation error in the DB as I edit an already exiting entity. Maybe your syntax will help me.