# can EF update exisiting row with a newly constructed entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I use EF in my application.

I want to add and save entities.

I have create a new entity object in my application and managed to add it to the DB.

Now I want to update an existing entity.

I have taken an existing entity from the DB,

presented it in the UI

and now I want to reflect the user changes.

Do I have to get the entity again from the DB and assign values to its properties, one by one?

I have tried to create a new entity and save this to the DB. It showed no errors, but it wasn;t reflected in the DB.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a form that posts a model object `model` and a controller with a working database context `_context`, you can make changes to an existing entity with the following code (properties may vary):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitForm(MyViewModel model)
{
    // Retrieve existing object
    var someObject = _context.Resources.OfType<MyEntityType>.Where
        (o => o.Id == model.Id).SingleOrDefault;

    // Assign new values to entity
    someObject.SomeProperty = model.SomeProperty;
    someObject.SomeOtherProperty = model.SomeOtherProperty;

    // Commit
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Update: Alternatively, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7642616/1043198) for details on how to attach a new object in place of an existing one.

Comment: I know this way. see: `Do I have to get the entity again from the DB and assign values to its properties, one by one?` I wanted to know if there is another way that allow me to upadte using a newly created EF?

Comment: @what's the difference between `DbContext API` and `ObjectContext`? when do I use each of them?

Comment: please see my following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085654/pk-violation-while-updating-via-ef/16086406?noredirect=1#16086406