# updaing\saving with EF violates a DB uniquness restriction

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using EF to update an entity.

Here is my code:

```
    public MamConfiguration_V1 Save(MamConfiguration_V1 item)
    {
            item.ThrowIfNull("item");

            mMaMDBEntities.MamConfiguration_V1.AddObject(item);

            mMaMDBEntities.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(item, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

            mMaMDBEntities.SaveChanges();

            return item;
    }
```

However in this way I get a PK violation erorr in the DB.

I prefer to use this way (creating a new EF entity) and marking it as

modified, how can I not break the uniquness restriction?

Comment: Does `MamConfiguration_V1` type objects have navigational properties?

Comment: yes. references to other entities

Answer (score -1):

If you are using this method to update the existing item, then you receive the exception because of the

```
  mMaMDBEntities.MamConfiguration_V1.AddObject(item);
```

line. It looks like with this code you are trying to put the item into your table for the second time. If I guessed right and you use this method to update your existing items, you just should remove this line - EF will automatically update the DB according to the changes you made to your object's fields.

Comment: I prefer to use this way (creating a new EF entity) and marking it as

modified, how can I not break the uniquness restriction?

Comment: If you want just "not break the uniqueness restriction", you can achieve this by assigning a new Id to your item before adding it to your collection.

Comment: In this case, you should not add your object to the collection each time you modified it. Just call SaveChanges on your context and your object will be updated without any additional uniqueness checks.